# Creating and deploying infopath forms in in sharepoint 2010 form libraries

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath-2007

I have created `infopath form` library in SharePoint sever2010. I am using Windows server 2008R2 OS and MS-Office 2010. When i clicked on "Add new document" in form library, it is asking a `.xsn` template.
I created a template using `infopath 2010` and assigning to it.
But it is saying that:

**`The element 'comment' is used but not declared in the DTD/Schema.`**.

I tried to publish it by using Infopath 2010, it is saying that :

`The element 'comment' is used but not declared in the DTD/Schema.`
again.

Can any one explain the procedure how to solve these errors....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error could occur if:

The template you created with InfoPath designer is not published to SharePoint - therefore when you click New -> New Document, you are asked to provide a template to use. Now if you supply any arbitrary template, you will get this error.

You can try following steps:

Publish the template you created to sharepoint Server. Check 'Enable this form to be filled by browser'.

You said very simple template so I am assuming there is no custom code associated.
Select publish to form library. Create a new form library, if not already done so; else use existing form library.

If you create new Form library from InfoPath, things are easy, when you click on 'new document' in your 'form library', you will see the form in browser.

If you publish to existing Form Library then follow these steps:

In your form library click settings -> Advanced settings.

1. Select 'Yes' for  'Allow management of content types?'.
2. For 'Default open behaviour for browser-enabled documents:'
   Select Use the server default (Open in the browser).
3. Click Ok.

Back on the settings page you should see: 'Add from existing site content types' in the 'content type' section. Click it and on the ' Add Content Types' page select group 'Microsoft Office Infopath' or 'Microsoft Infopath', which ever your content group is, and you should see the name of your form. Add this and click ok.

Back in your Form Library, you should see two InfoPath forms on your New button.

Well that's that, you can get rid of one of them.

Comment: the information you have given is some what helpful to me. But as i said i am using infopath 2010. I didnt find the Check 'Enable this form to be filled by browser' in infopath designer.